# What is the idiomatic way to handle api versions

Tags: go, routes, versioning

I'm creating a server in Go intended for a mobile app.  I need to be able to support multiple versions of the API for cases were users don't update the app. The main concern with the versioning, is to return data in the correct format for the version of the mobile app.

I've seen that there are three basic ways to do this.
A.  One way is by having one route handler on "/", and then allowing that function to parse the url for versioning.
Example:

```
func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", routes.ParseFullURI)
}
```

B. Use a library such as gorilla/mux to handle patterns within the router, but I saw some [warnings that this can be too slow](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/a-mux-showdown#benchmarks).
Example:

```
  func main() {
            mux.HandleFunc("{version:}/", routes.ParseVersionForHome)
            mux.HandleFunc("{version:}/getData", routes.ParseVersionForGetDAta)
            mux.HandleFunc("{version:}/otherCall", routes.ParseVersionForOtherCall)
            }
```

C. Have individual urls that don't change, but based on the header, split into different versions.
Example:

```
func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("/", routes.ParseHeaderForVersionForHome)
   http.HandleFunc("/getData", routes.ParseHeaderForVersionForGetData)
   http.HandleFunc("/otherCall", routes.ParseHeaderForVersionForOtherCall)
}
```

I'm concerned that option 1 will be too messy code wise.  I'm concerned that option 2 will be too slow performance wise, and I'm concerned that option 3 will be difficult for the client to handle, or will get confusing since the version isn't clearly labeled.

Which method is the most idiomatic for Go, and will result in the greatest performance for a mobile app which will be polling often?

Comment: If you're talking about an API over HTTP(S) then something like `http://example.com/api/v1/…` is common. Or are you more asking how to implement such a pattern in a Go server?

Comment: I'm asking how to go about it in a Go Server.  I'll explain further in my question.

Comment: 1 and 2 are basically equivalent, you're just doing the routing yourself in the first. If gorilla/mux is too slow, don't use it (even the default HandleFunc is using a "router": `http.ServeMux`). 3 has nothing to do with Go, it's just whether you want to make your clients use headers or not (which shouldn't be a big deal)

Comment: Well,  3 has to do with Go because it clearly defines the possible routes in the class, rather than in the function implementation.  I.e. where do you see the list of supported apis.  I'll make that more clear in the example.

Comment: Many routers will allow for grouping different routes. You might want to look into that.

Comment: @placeybordeaux  Thanks.  That led me to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298646/how-can-i-create-separate-route-groups-with-different-middleware-in-goji-golang   Might be the right direction.  Do you want to turn that into a full answer?  Need to go see if goji has benchmarks.

Comment: Don't freak out about router speed. At https://github.com/julienschmidt/go-http-routing-benchmark you see timings (for the "route a single request" benchmarks) in the thousands of nanoseconds, as in microseconds, as in thousandths of milliseconds. That is so small a cost compared to, say, a database write that it's hard for me to even grasp it intuitively.

Comment: (To be clear, I do think echo is a neat achievement! Cool to see a nontrivial non-allocating component. But I don't want anyone to feel like they have to use it to end up with good API performance.)

Comment: @twotwotwo I'm going to be using redis as the database, so I need to make sure that the parsing of the url, isn't the bottleneck.

Comment: @Avik It absolutely won't be. Talking to Redis will be an order of magnitude (single digit to tens of milliseconds) slower than your routing. Even with more than 5,000 routes, your router won't even come close to that. Also note that Echo *does* allocate - it creates a pool. Using the pool (get/put) doesn't count towards benchmark allocation output.

Comment: @elithrar I'm confused now.  Redis does about 72 requests per millisecond.     Echo is benchmarked at 4.5 milliseconds per variable based request?  Am I reading the numbers wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many routing frameworks that allow for grouping, for instance with echo (a very good framework if you want speed)

```
package main

import "github.com/labstack/echo"

func ping(c *echo.Context) {
        c.String(200, "pong")
}

func main() {
        e := echo.New()

        v1 := e.Group("/v1")
        v1.Get("/ping", ping)

        v2 := e.Group("/v2")
        v2.Get("/ping", ping)

        e.Run(":4444")
}
```

I think this is quite clean.

I am sure many other frameworks allow for this. I know for a fact martini does, but that is not an idiomatic framework...

Comment: Thanks. Now I just need to find the best library for my needs , but this seems to be the most common approach to versioning in Go.  The list of libraries that support grouping and that are fast seem almost endless!

Comment: Hi, I've been searching the net, and having a hard time understanding if ping is the same function, and if so, how I differentiate which group called it to return different results.

Comment: Ping is the same function. From the context of ping you could look up the URL that was given. I was assuming that you would call different functions for different versions.